# How to add "current desktop location" to context menu of desktop [windows 8 x64]

Tags: windows-8, context-menu

In Windows 7 I used "right click extender" from the Windows Club

it was using this code:

```
'Open Desktop Wallpaper File Location

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strCurWP =""

On Error Resume Next
strCurWP = WshShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General\WallpaperSource")
On Error Goto 0

If Trim(strCurWP) = "" Then
    MsgBox "No Wallpaper selected for Desktop Slideshow"
Else
    If fso.FileExists(strCurWP) Then
        WshShell.run "explorer.exe" & " /select," & strCurWP
    Else
        MsgBox "Cannot find target for " & strCurWP
    End If
End If

'RIGHT-CLICK EXTENDER V2
'Created by: Lee Whittington (UntameDKreationZ) for The Windows Club
```

My question "what is the new registry path of desktop wallpaper in windows 8?"

Comment: What makes you think the registry key changed?

Comment: *"current desktop location"*... Is the desktop not always in the same place?